# Modify class members value

Tags: c#

I have a class and constructor in order to initiate it like this:

```
public class Merchant
{
    public int userID;
    public int clubID;
    public short categoryID;
    public string posTerminalID;
    public string name;
    public double score;
    public double subClubSharePercent;
    public double simClubSharePercent;
    public bool isActive;
    public string modificationDatetime;

    public Merchant() 
    { 

    }
    public Merchant(int uID, int cID, Int16 aID, string pID, string n, double s, double sSp, double sCp, Boolean iA, DateTime dt)
    {
        Date da = new Date();

        this.userID = uID;
        this.clubID = cID;
        this.categoryID = aID;
        this.posTerminalID = pID;
        this.name = n;
        this.score = s;
        this.subClubSharePercent = sSp;
        this.simClubSharePercent = sCp;
        this.isActive = iA;
        this.modificationDatetime = da;
    }
}
```

how can i modify the class members value:

1. Use the constructor method again?
2. Create modify class and call it?

what is the differences between initializing class with constructor and  syntax?
thank you.

Comment: You just want to change the values of the items in the class?  Definitely don't want to call the constructor again.  You should turn these into properties, e.g., `public bool IsActive { get; set; }` and then you can change them via `classInstance.IsActive = true`.

Comment: Your question makes zero sense.  First of all, it isn't a custom constructor...it's just a constructor. It just happens to have parameters making it a non-default constructor. Second of all, you don't use constructors to modify components of a class.  You use them to create new instances of the object.  As such, you only want to add methods to your class that you can invoke to change the state of the object, per object.

Comment: i dont want to use the setter getter.

Comment: why it makes no sense? i just asked which one is better solution!!?

Comment: Consider using properties.

Comment: @David why you don,t want to use properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dan Field has definitely given you an adequate answer, but I figured I'd chime in with a few tidbits as well.

- Constructors are useful for setting variables that otherwise could never be set by the developer. These include private fields, private functions, and private properties.
- You've declared many public fields. You know they're fields because there is no 'setter' or 'getter' function. Properties, however, are defined by having the getter and setter functions. Setters and getters are not just a `C#` phenomenon, they're useful in many object-oriented languages.
- In `C#`, public properties can be set by the programmer whenever necessary - initializing public properties through the constructor (with a few exceptions) isn't necessarily useful. That said, there are patterns where *requiring* every field to be passed into the constructor means that the object can't exist without all of its info. In your case, that's not apparently a concern as you have a *parameterless* constructor in `public Merchant()`.
- `C#` also allows for object initialization right in its syntax, without the need to pass in every property through parameters in the constructor.

Consider the difference here:

```
//Constructor with all parameters
public Merchant(int uID, int cID, Int16 aID, string pID, string n, double s, double sSp,
double sCp, Boolean iA, DateTime dt) {

  Date da = new Date();

  this.userID = uID;
  this.clubID = cID;
  this.categoryID = aID;
  this.posTerminalID = pID;
  this.name = n;
  this.score = s;
  this.subClubSharePercent = sSp;
  this.simClubSharePercent = sCp;
  this.isActive = iA;
  this.modificationDatetime = da;
}

//Code using it
Merchant merchant = new Merchant(uID, cID, aID, pID, n, s, sSp, sCp, iA, dt);
```

versus

```
//Constructor with no parameters
public Merchant( ) { }

//Code using it
Merchant merchant = new Merchant( ) {
  userID = uID,
  categoryID = aID,
  isActive = iA,
  modificationDateTime = da
};
```

The main differences being that with the first method, you're **enforcing** all parameters to be present. The second method, however, gives the *user* more flexibility to instantiate only what they want/need.

Answer (score 2):

You can only call a class constructor once.  Once the object is constructed, it's constructed and that's just it (leaving aside any weird attempts to invoke the code in a constructor through reflection).

If you want to be able to use a single method to change the values of the class after it's been constructed, you'll have to write a method to do so (perhaps you don't want someone to change only one member variable at a time? running validations against the variables that, for thread-safety reasons, you wan tto run all at once?).

If you don't want outside objects to be able to modify the values of the class, you should probably make those public properties have a private set, e.g.:

```
public bool isActive { get; private set; }
```

This will make it clear that property can be read but not written outside the class itself, and prevent a non-member from modifying the variable.

If you want the properties to be settable only by a constructor (and not even a member method can change them), mark them `readonly`.  But realize that to get new values here, you'll have to make a completely new object (i.e. `new Merchant(param, param, param....`).